# How to submit a form generated from an ajax $.get?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, mysqli

I have this page on document ready [image: document ready]

Once a customer is selected from the customer select input an `ajax $.get` is performed onchange and displays the billing address form and associated values if any from the database `customers`

**jquery EXAMPLE PURPOSES ONLY**

```
$("#cus").change(function(){
   cusValue = $(this).val();
   $.get("info.php", {cusValue: cusValue}, function(data){
      $("#info").html(data);
   });
});
```

[image]

**HTML EXAMPLE PURPOSES ONLY**

```
<form action='".update($conn)."' method='post'>
  <select name='cus'><option value='".$cus."'>".$cus."</option></select>
  <input name='a1' type='text' value='".$a2."'>
  <input name='a2' type='text' value='".$a3."'>
   ...
  <input name='submit' type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>
```

**PHP EXAMPLE PURPOSES ONLY**

```
function update($conn){
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $cus = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cus']);
    $a1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['a1']);
    $a2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['a2']);
    $a3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['a3']);
    $a4 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['a4']);
    $a5 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['a5']);
    $a6 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['a6']);

    mysqli_query($conn,  "UPDATE customers SET a1 ='$a1', a2 ='$a2', a3 ='$a3', a4 ='$a4', a5 ='$a5', a6 ='$a6' WHERE customer = '$cus'");
        }
     }
```

I do not have any syntax errors

On a normal page form gets submitted and myqli table is updated. However when the form that has been generated into an ajaxed `div` is submitted myqli table does not get updated after submit button is clicked! Is there a way around this?

Comment: `form action='".update($conn)."'`  This code doesn't make sense.  A form `action` attribute specified the path to which the form is sent.  You seem to think that it's a function that gets triggered when the form gets submitted, but that's not the case.

Comment: You're attempting to call a php function from your form `action`. That is not possible

Comment: Lets focus on the problem at hand please.. But if `form action='".update($conn)."'` is such an issue my page is php controlled and echoed. For normal html syntax would be `form action='<?php update($conn);?>'` to call a function from an external source included on the page. `e.g <?php include 'functionList.php'; ?>` make sense??

Comment: No, that is _not_ what the form `action` attribute is for.  (unless your function returned a URI, which yours doesn't).  I think you need to study up on the difference between client-side and server-side.